# Docker for Windows 10 proxy settings in containers

Tags: docker, proxy, windows-10, docker-compose, containers

I am behind corporate proxy and and running window 10, have set proxy setting in docker [window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ywtO.png)
this allows me to pull images from dockerhub, however the same proxy settings are used when running containers( [documented here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#proxies))

This causes issues when I want to consume http endpoints exposed by one container in another container on same network , all setup through docker-compose yml file

`version: "3.3"
services:
  service1:
    image: "some_service1"
    environment:
        BASEAPP: service2:4000
  service2:
    image: "some_service2"`

So my questions is - 
Whats the right way to have proxy setting to pull down images from internet but not use the same settings in containers.

I can comeup with naming convention for my local container names and add then to `no_proxy` settings, however that seems like a hack.

Comment: What is your no_proxy look like?

Comment: @VonC , my no_proxy is ```NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1```. If i add ```service2``` to it, the system works.

Comment: @traceLog were you able to solve this issue? In my case, my proxy is not propagating to containers

Comment: @amique no I have not found a clean solution to this, I am adding ```service2``` to my ```NO_PROXY``` for now.